# OpenGL texture dissappearing when I get didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out this bug in my code. When my app starts, my main ViewController has an openGL view set as it's view property, in:

```
- (void) loadView {
  glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [glView setAnimationFrameInterval: kAnimationFrameInterval];
  [glView startAnimation];

  UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

  UIImage *infoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
  [infoButton setImage:infoImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [infoImage release];

  infoButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
  [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 48.0f, 48.0f);
  infoButton.clipsToBounds = NO;
  [glView addSubview:infoButton];

  glView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

  self.view = glView;
```

}

and in

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    glView = nil;
   [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

When the user clicks on infoButton this view controller presents a modal view controller (called from showInfo) that has a tabBarController with more viewControllers inside.

My problem is, whenever I receive a didReceiveMemoryWarning in any viewController the textures from my main Viewcontroller get released, as expected, but for some reason I can't reload them again, so the first time it happens I get the shapes without the textures, but if the user clicks on the infoButton again and tries to return, the app crashes.

So my question is, should I keep the glView alive at all costs or should I set it to nil and release it whenever I get this memory warning? I have read some questions and Apple documentation saying that you should recreate this stuff again. In didReceiveMemoryWarning:

> "Your implementation of this method should free up as much memory as possible by purging cached data objects that can be recreated (or reloaded from disk) later."

I want to be able to do this before the user goes back to the openGL view, so that the UI doesn't lag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let me notice that calling

```
   glView = nil;
```

will not send a release to your EAGLView, hence you have a memory leak here (because assigning it to self.view will also increase its retain counter).

Are you sure that `viewDidUnload` is actually called? It should only for views that are not currently displayed. If so, could you add more info about the kind of crash/console log, etc?

Taking into account the possibility of leaks, I would consider that maybe the app is killed due to excessive memory use. A good hint at this is if you see a `signal (0)` at the end of your console log.

Comment: I was doing [glView release] in the dealloc method, is this wrong? I get no warning or crash in gdb, the screen just goes dark and the app stops.

Comment: If for some reason `    glView = nil;` is executed in `viewDidUnload`, then you have a leak, because `dealloc` will find `glView` to be nil and will not be able to release it. See also my edit...

Comment: It gets the message because when I get the didReceiveMemoryWarning the controller the view that is present is the one from the modal view controller. Let me debug it one more time, and I'll get back to you

Comment: 2012-05-10 17:34:36.480 App[7611:707] Received memory warning. Level=1
2012-05-10 17:34:36.548 App[7611:707] ViewDidUnload called

Comment: For some reason, moving the loadView code to viewDidLoad avoided the problem, but thanks for pointing me to the right direction @sergio!